# PhantomJS driver don't see reactjs component on page

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to send data in form fields on page, which work on http-server, from my python script. But when I trying to run my script with PhantomJS driver, I always get the error:

```
Unable to find element with id "x"
```

Even if I see in console that my script is loaded successfully(green light). But when I use Chrome driver all goes fine. I was tried

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "RCPN")))
```

but this gives me timeoutexception error. My current code:

```
from random_data_generator import RandomDataGenerator
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(
executable_path='c:\phantomjs\\bin\phantomjs.exe')
driver.get('http://someurl')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "blanks")))

driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)  # optional
recipient = RandomDataGenerator()
sender = RandomDataGenerator()

driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')  # save a screenshot to disk
rcpn_name = driver.find_element_by_id('RCPN')
rcpn.send_keys(recipient.get_name())
print rcpn_name
```

What can be the problem?